# ng-show not working with class on the div

Tags: css, angularjs

Right now, I have

```
<div class="error-msg" ng-show="displayError()">Error Messages: {{error}}</div>
```

Which isn't displaying correctly, unless I remove class="error-msg" from the div.

And the CSS for my .error-msg is:

```
.error-msg {
height: 40px;
overflow: auto;
display: none;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

What is the correct way for me do ng-show, while keeping the class on my div?

Comment: `display: none` could give you a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove `display:none` from the css rule. ng-show will apply `ng-hide` class on the element which has `display:none` (with `!important` to forcefully override any other display:block or other display attributes) if displayError returns false, otherwise it relies on the rule that you provide and you are hiding it there (So it does not display).

```
.error-msg {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```